# mapping / passing down redux actions to stateless component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

After changing one of my components, (Profile.js) from a class to a function to simplify and have cleaner code, the onClick triggering of a redux action (like) no longer does anything.

Some have pointed out the action needs to be map differently, but I'm not sure why as I'm still new to redux and it's confusing as to why it works fine as a class but not as a function.

What adds to the confusion is that I'm also using react thunk to make things async.

**User.js**

```
import { fetchUser, like } from '../../actions/userActions';

class User extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { username } = this.props.match.params;
        this.props.fetchUser(username);
    }

    render() {
        const { like, user } = this.props;

        return (
            <Profile user={user} like={like} />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.store.user
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchUser, like})(User);
```

**Profile.js Before**

```
import { like, user } from '../../actions/userActions';

class Profile extends React.Component {
    const { like, user } = this.props

    return (
        <a onClick={() => like(user.username)}>Like</a>
    )
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, {like}){Profile)
```

**Profile.js After**

```
const Profile = (props) => {
    const { like, user } = props

    return (
        <a onClick={() => like(user.username)}>Like</a>
    )
}
```

**actions.js**

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3001'

function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

export const like = (username) => dispatch => {
    fetch(`${url}/like/${username}`, {credentials: 'include', method: 'post'})
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>
        dispatch({
            type: LIKE,
            payload: res
    })
  )
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
}


export const fetchUser = (username) => dispatch => {
    fetch(`${url}/${username}`, {credentials: 'include'})
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_USER,
        payload: res
    })
  ) 
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)) 
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_USER:
        return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload.user
    };    

    case LIKE:
        return {
        ...state,
            user: {
                ...state.user,
                meta: {
                    ...state.user.meta,
                    like: action.payload.like
                }
            }
        };
```

**store.js**

```
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

**console.log of like in Profile.js**

```
const Profile = (props) => {
    const { user, like } = props
    console.log(like)

ƒ like(username) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    fetch(url + '/like/' + username, { credentials: 'include', method: 'post' }).then(handleErrors).then(function (res) {
      return res.json();
    …
```

If I were to create a normal function such as

```
const test = () => { console.log('test') }
```

and change the `onClick={}` in **Profile.js** to use that, it works fine.

Comment: We need to reproduce that before suppose something.

Comment: I don't believe that is a redux problem. Where does the var `${url}` comes from? 0.o

Comment: What errors your console present to?

Comment: Your code in `User` component seems to be invalid. Have you copied it correctly?

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues, I've updated the code. ${url} comes from a const in actions.js, there are no errors and I've also updated to include the console.log of the like action.

Comment: @DenysKotsur, what's invalid?

Comment: @totalnoob You wrote `render()` inside of  `componentDidMount` and `mapStateToProps` inside of component. I think, something bad with brackets which caused bad formatting.

Comment: ahh. bad copy and paste. updated now @DenysKotsur

Answer (score 1):

You should create handler in the `User` component, call your action creator there and pass it as a callback to child `Profile` component.

So, your code will looks like:

```
import { like } from '../../actions/userActions';

class User extends React.Component {
    ...

    onClickHandler = username => {
        return () => {
            this.props.like(username);
        }
    }

    render() {
       const { user } = this.props;
       return <Profile user={user} onClickHandler={this.onClickHandler} />   
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.store.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchUser, like})(User);
```

Then, call `onClickHandler` in your `Profile` component:

```
const Profile = props => {
    const { onClickHandler, user } = props;

    return (
        <button onClick={onClickHandler(user.username)}>Like</button>
    )
}
```

Hope it will helps.

Comment: this works! can you please explain how this works and why this is needed?